# SQLite suitable for concurrent reading?

Tags: php, database, web, sqlite

Will an SQLite database perform well to around 50 reads/second without locking?

I'm trying to decide whether it'd be feasible for use on a PHP website that won't get 'written' to very often - it'll be mostly reads of the same data from a small handful of tables

Comment: Forgot to mention - it won't hold much data, maybe a thousand or so rows of very little text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. The concurrent reading/writing will actually be serialized by SQLite so you don't need to care about it.

For details : http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html