# Python SQLite3 using multiple processes for concurrent reading: often hangs without raising error on big dataset

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, data-science, multiple-processes

**Overview**:
I am trying to create a large number of variables (wide dataset) for a financial data analysis project. I have a pandas dataframe "position_history" with 140,000 rows, each containing a stock and buy and sell dates/prices.

I have a function create_domain that takes inputs (stock, buy_date, sell_date) and:

1. makes a query to my SQLite3 database to extract the time-series for
   that stock given those dates.
2. constructs my variables using the time-series

I apply the function create_domain to position_history using df.apply

When I run my code sequentially it takes about 4 hours to construct my variables, and I would like to speed this up using multiple processes, since I will have to do this many times and may need a much wider dataset.

For multiple processes, I split position_history into chunks vertically, creating a list of dataframes. I pass this list to joblib (multiprocessing). My code almost always hangs indefinitely without throwing any errors (but sometimes runs on small samples).

My suspicion has been that there is a problem arising from my worker processes trying to read the same SQL table concurrently.

**I have tried the following remedies**:

- opened a new connection (sqlalchemy.create_engine) inside the function create_domain so each worker process gets it's own engine/connection
- following the sqlalchemy documentation (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-use-engines-connections-sessions-with-python-multiprocessing-or-os-fork)

  - changed poolclass to NullPool, which disables multiple connections within one engine, forcing the engine to open and close a new connection for each transaction
  - just in case, used engine.dispose() for each child to make sure to flush all engine connections and get new ones
  - Note -- These solutions were meant to force sqlite3 to not share any connections across threads, which wouldn't work ([Is it possible with SQLAlchemy to share SQLite database among multiple Python processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315717/is-it-possible-with-sqlalchemy-to-share-sqlite-database-among-multiple-python-pr))
- under joblib (https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)

  - tried using the 'threading' backend instead of 'multiprocessing'. This worked but didn't speed up the code by much, which from reading about threading here ([Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)) makes sense because threading does not actually allow you to use multiple cpus.
  - tried using the memmaping technique since pandas has some numpy in it; I don't think this was a relevant fix for me

**Related stackoverflow entries**:

- I would like to use multiple processes, not multithreading as
  discussed:
  [python multiple threaded processes for running executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306078/python-multiple-threaded-processes-for-running-executables); 
  [Python sqlite3 and concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393554/python-sqlite3-and-concurrency); 
  [SQLite3 and Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969820/sqlite3-and-multiprocessing); 
  *I don't understand the last answer on this one

  - I am only trying to read, and not write, so I'm not sure if the management of the SQLite locking mechanisms is necessary, as
    discussed:
    [SQLite suitable for concurrent reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322773/sqlite-suitable-for-concurrent-reading); 
    [Concurrent writing with sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207193/concurrent-writing-with-sqlite3)
  - This post says it should work in theory: [sqlite3 concurrent access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite3-concurrent-access); Note -- I don't think WAL mode would help me because I am only reading.

**(Psuedo) Code snippets**
My call to joblib:

```
x = Parallel(n_jobs =4)(delayed(create_domain)(chunk, other inputs) for chunk in chunks)  
# where each chunk is a portion of the position_history df
```

My create_domain function:

```
def create_domain (df=position_history, inputs):  
    # create vars using row x of position_history  
    f = lambda x: sql_query_and_create_vars(inputs, x['column'])  
    result = df.apply(f, axis=1)  
    return result
```

**Summary**:
My code hangs forever, crashes the kernel, and doesn't raise any errors. I would appreciate any insight as to:

- Why this is happening?
- How can I fix it?
- Is there simply a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I did my best to vectorize, and optimize my SQL queries.
- Is this a problem with SQLite3? Would something like MySQL work better?
- Any tips; I'm new to coding/python/data science.

Details:
I am on a super computer cluster, running Linux, and using iPython on Python 3.4.3.

This is my first stackoverflow question -- sorry in advance for faux pas and thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like your app is severely IO-bound. Having multiple processes in this case would likely not help. It sounds like you're attempting to execute 140k queries, which *of course* is going to take a *really* long time. The way to fix this is to batch your queries. Instead of executing a query for each of the 140k, see if you can execute one query per chunk.

Comment: Hi univerio, thanks for your comment. Yes, most of the time is spent on the SQL queries according to the light profiling I've done. I could reduce the number of queries, and do more of the processing on the pandas side (in memory). For example, I could make one query to pull the time-series for many stocks, and then split those into individual stocks once I've got them in the pandas df. Is pandas generally faster than SQL for this?

Comment: Yes, for the simple reason that you're using memory instead of disk. You only need to use the disk if you don't have enough memory.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this: I'll pull the whole stocks table into a dataframe, then I'll put that dataframe into a SQLite database that exists only in memory (https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). Then I should be able to use my existing SQL code and gain the advantage of having everything in mem; and maybe multiprocessing will work too. Thanks again.

Comment: If all DB accesses are read only, try using the [`unix-none` VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) to remove all locking overhead.

Comment: Update -- I took univerio's advice and tried a different approach that ended up working out (though I did not solve the SQL multiprocessing problem). I did try to use an in-memory :memory: SQLite DB, which sped things up by about 15% but still couldn't handle multiprocessing the way I had it set-up. Then, I moved over to pandas: I put the entire stock table into a pandas dataframe and "queried" that instead, and that worked with multiprocessing. Thanks for the tips.